# Dynamic cast, list of objects conversion, templates

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-cast

There are 2 classes:

```
class A
{
   private:
        double a1, a2;
   ...
};

class B : public A
{
   private:
        double b1, b2;
};
```

and a generic container

```
template <typename Item>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};


template <typename Item>
class GList
{
private:
            typename TList <Item>::Type items;
```

}   ;

There 4 containers of objects

```
GList <A> A1;
GList <B> B1;
GList <A*> A2;
GList <B*> B2;
```

Are those conversions (up/down) allowed or not:

```
1] GList <B> B3 = dynamic_cast <GList <B> &> (A1);
2] GList <A> A3 = static_cast <GList <A> &> (B1);
3] GList <B*> B4 = dynamic_cast <GList <B*> &> (A2);
4] GList <A*> A4 = static_cast <GList <A*> &> (B2);
```

Is there any way how to convert list of objects to list of parent objects and vice versa?

**Updated question**

And what about reinterpret_cast?

```
1] GList <B> B3 = reinterpret_cast <GList <B> &> (A1);
2] GList <A> A3 = reinterpret_cast <GList <A> &> (B1);
3] GList <B*> B4 = reinterpret_cast <GList <B*> &> (A2);
4] GList <A*> A4 = reinterpret_cast <GList <A*> &> (B2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GList <B> B3 = dynamic_cast <GList <B> &> (A1);
```

`dynamic_cast` works with only polymorphic type. Here `GList` is not polymorphic. Hence it would not even compile!

If you make this polymorphic, even then this cast wouldn't work, since there is no relationship between `GList<B>` and `<GList<A>`. They're like two different *unrelated* types.

In fact, they're related in the same way as `GList_B` and `GList_A` are related (suppose, if you define two different classes with such names). Or even better, they're related in the same way as Java and JavaScript, Car and Carpet are related.

Comment: @Robo: Then how do you it be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, containers are not *covariant*; there is no relationship between `std::vector<Base>` and `std::vector<Derived>` (nor between `std::vector<Base *>` and `std::vector<Derived *>`.

In the case of the value-type containers, there's the fundamental problem that typically, `sizeof(Derived) > sizeof(Base)`.  So all the internal pointer maths in `std::vector` will break horribly if you try to coerce one to the other.

In the case of the pointer-type containers, these conversion may "work" (if you can get them to compile), but the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no valid conversions between containers of types, regardless of whether there are valid conversions between the types themselves.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic_cast and static_cast work if the objects have a relationship (like A and B).

But a template create a completely new class, there's no way to use these casts. Maybe you can try reinterpret_cast, but it's not safe...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a list of objects to a list of parent objects. If you could, then i could do this :

```
GList<A>& a = convert_the_thing(B1);
a.add_a_element(A());
```

and i would have inserted a A into your list of B.